# GDB: How does one format breakpoint output?

Tags: debugging, assembly, formatting, x86, gdb

Currently, I'm running GDB with the set disassemble-next-line on setting. For each line, this gives me a format that looks like:

```
   0x08120921 <arith_driver+1>:  57     push   %edi
```

Instead, I'd like the line to look like:

```
0x8120921<arith_driver+1>data.c:2577    push %edi   M[0xffffc9c4]=0x084073c2 esp=0xffffc9c4
```

where M[address] represents a location in memory and esp refers to the register.  Everything else is fairly self-explanatory. It seems like there should be a way to specify assembly code output format, but I can't find anything. Any help?

Comment: gdb doesn't know what each instruction does, so it doesn't know what things it should print for you. (I assume you do not always want to print `M[esp]` and `esp`).

Comment: @Jester Fair. The third column doesn't matter quite so much. Just getting the machine instructions to print the source line along side them and to not print the bytes representing the machine code would be enough. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this.  You can maybe do some of it by modifying the gdb source code.